# power limit on wireless FM microphone transmitters

Tags: transmitter, fm, fcc, microphone

I am building a "toy" radio station as a teaching tool for high school students to work with. I intend to use a small (short-range) wireless FM microphone module as the transmitter. What is the legal limit for the transmitting power of an FM wireless mic that operates in the 88-108 MHz broadcast band?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered at least three times. [1. Here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/what-are-the-us-rules-about-unlicensed-low-power-transmissions), [2. Here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/9184/resort-fm-radio-station/9458#9458), and [3. Here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/7267/is-it-legal-to-broadcast-an-fm-radio-signal-with-a-raspberry-pi-zero). Closing it as a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, I will read all the answers. -NN